# print number of data, average and standard deviation from the data in the chart of matplotlib at Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I love to use "zoom" button in the chart of matplotlib.
I want to print number of data, average and standard deviation for the data in the chart **whenever I change the ZOOM.**
It can be in the console or chart. It will be great if I can see some statistics of data in the chart anywhere. Could you advise me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question wasn't clear. 
Anyway I found the solution by myself from asking [a question in matplotlib discourse](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/print-statistics-for-time-series-data-whenever-changing-zoom-level/20744)!

I realized that matplotlib is much broader concept than I thought.
The following solution is not correct answer for the question because it prints stats only when the button is pressed instead of whenever the xlim is changed. But I like this way more because I can print stats only when I want.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


df = pd.DataFrame()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
df['time'] = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
df['data'] = np.sin(2*np.pi*df['time'])
df.plot.scatter(x='time', y='data', s=1, ax=ax)


def print_stats(event):
    start, end = ax.get_xlim()
    cond1 = df['time'] > start 
    cond2 = df['time'] < end
    df_tmp = df[cond1 & cond2]
    print(df_tmp.describe())

b_loc_size = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
b = Button(b_loc_size, 'Stats', hovercolor='green')
b.on_clicked(print_stats)
plt.show()
```